# How to make elements reappear after animation with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple JS program and am having some trouble. You can view it here

http://codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/mOGVEy?editors=0010

Enter in your name and press enter, it will animate your name, but the letters disappear after the animation, which is understandable. what I don't understand is why my setTimeout isn't working and making them re-appear.

So here is the basic problem:

```
    var timeOut = (a / 2 + 1) * 1000;
          document.querySelector(".spanWrap").style.width = char.length * 60 + "px";
                  setTimeout(function() {
            thang.style.opacity = "1"
            thang.style.marginTop = "0";
    }, timeOut);
```

So hopefully that is all the info you will need, if not reference my pen, this is all in a for loop and if you see undefined variables here, they are defined in my pen.

So if someone can tell me what I did wrong that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please also show all the relevant code (i.e. `a`, `thang` and your animation code).

Comment: I have all the relevant code in the link I provided.

Comment: It is more appropriate to post your code here, in your question, than to make us go out and find it.

Comment: Well I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [infamous closure bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue#1451043).

I noticed that you are transpiring using Babel. Using `let` instead of `var` for your variables local to your loop should fix the issue. Notice that in your broken CodePen, the last letter stays while the rest disappear. That is because your `thang` is always equal to the last letter by the time the timeout handlers execute (the loop has concluded long before).

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObaVyb.

Also, a better idea might be to take a look at [`animation-fill-mode: forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode), which allows you to retain styles after animations have been run.

Finally, for those of you not using ES6, this code will allow you to achieve the same functionality without creating another wrapper function. (Essentially, `setTimeout` allows you to pass arguments to your callback when you register each  handler.)

```
setTimeout(function (thang) {
    thang.style.opacity = "1"
    thang.style.marginTop = "0";
  }, timeOut, thang);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you have several `timeouts` in `for` loop, that needs references to `thang` variables, but when your `timeouts` will be executed `thang` variable will be equal to the last `thang` in the cycle, so all the `timeout` would have the same reference. Hope it's clear.

So, to fix that,  you need to bind your `timeouts` with `thangs` variables, one by one.

For example, you can do it with closures:

```
(function(thang) {setTimeout(function() {
    thang.style.opacity = "1"
    thang.style.marginTop = "0";
  }, timeOut);})(thang)
```